# jQuery File Upload - file name 'undefined' when file is cropped

Tags: jquery, file, upload, filenames, crop

I have install jQuery File Upload to my site because I need a system that crop files before it is uploaded to my server.

When I choose the file with the plugin, the file name is correct:

[image]

After I cropped it, the file was renamed with "undefined":

[image]

I am using

- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

with cropper.js

https://github.com/tkvw/jQuery-File-Upload

And when it is uploaded to my server, if there is more than one file, they subscribes each other because of the "same file name". And there is only one on the server with that name.

Comment: Can you share some code how you do the cropping

Comment: I'm using the same files on this repository

Comment: https://github.com/tkvw/jQuery-File-Upload

I think it is on the js folder